# ASP.NET MVC - JSON.NET adds escaped quotes around my keys and values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have an `MVC` `ApiController` class in which I am trying to return JSON.

I am using [Newtonsoft's](http://json.net) `JSON.NET` serializer in the method:

```
// GET api/packages/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    var Packages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Packages.Add("Package 1", "One");
    Packages.Add("Package 2", "Two");
    Packages.Add("Package 3", "Three");
    Packages.Add("Package 4", "Four");

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Packages);
}
```

But when viewed in my browser, I see the response:

```
"{\"Package 1\":\"One\",\"Package 2\":\"Two\",\"Package 3\":\"Three\",\"Package 4\":\"Four\"}"
```

with all the quotes escaped. This is obviously not readable by my client. Can anyone see where I am going wrong here? The `content-type` is returned as `application/json` (which is shown in Chrome developer tools also).

Comment: Is there any reason that you used `JSON.NET`?

Comment: @AbbasAmiri Not really. There were a lot of snippets for it when I googled `JSON` and `.NET`. Is there a better way to do this without `JSON.NET`?

Comment: Of course, I will put the solution as an answer, I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple method without using JSON.NET.

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> Get()
 {
        var packages = new Dictionary<string, string>
                           {
                               {"Package 1", "One"},
                               {"Package 2", "Two"},
                               {"Package 3", "Three"},
                               {"Package 4", "Four"}
                           };

        return packages;
 }
```

The result in IE is

```
{"Package 1":"One","Package 2":"Two","Package 3":"Three","Package 4":"Four"}
```

Comment: Yup! That did it. So much simpler than I was making it. Thanks!